# Is there a way to add scoped service which is repository to ASP.NET Core 7 MVC?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, .net-7.0

I have a category db. I need to build controller part for CRUD operations. I created repository interface, class and also configure the controller part but I can't add the service to Program.cs file. How can I fix that ?

**IRepository.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        // T - Category
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using Bulky.DataAccess.Data;
using Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Bulky.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _dbSet = _db.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
            query = query.Where(filter);
            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            _dbSet.RemoveRange(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

**ICategoryRepository.cs**

```
using Bulky.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface ICategoryRepository : IRepository<Category>
    {
        void Update(Category obj);
        void Save();
    }
}
```

**CategoryRepository.cs**

```
using Bulky.DataAccess.Data;
using Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Bulky.Models;

namespace Bulky.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class CategoryRepository : Repository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(Category obj)
        {
            _db.Categories.Update(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryController.cs**

```
using Bulky.DataAccess.Data;
using Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Bulky.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BulkyWeb.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepo;

        public CategoryController(ICategoryRepository db)
        {
            _categoryRepo = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Category> objCategoryList = _categoryRepo.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(objCategoryList);
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Category obj)
        {
            if (obj.Name == obj.DisplayOrder.ToString())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("name", "the displayorder cannot exactly match the name.");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _categoryRepo.Add(obj);
                _categoryRepo.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Category created successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } 

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Category? categoryFromDb = _categoryRepo.Get(u => u.Id == id);
            //Category? categoryFromDb1 = _db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
            //Category? categoryFromDb2 = _db.Categories.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (categoryFromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(categoryFromDb);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Category obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _categoryRepo.Update(obj);
                _categoryRepo.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Category updated successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Category? categoryFromDb = _categoryRepo.Get(u => u.Id == id);

            if (categoryFromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(categoryFromDb);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public IActionResult DeletePOST(int? id)
        {
            Category? obj = _categoryRepo.Get(u => u.Id == id);

            if (obj == null) 
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _categoryRepo.Remove(obj);
            _categoryRepo.Save();

            TempData["success"] = "Category deleted successfully";

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Bulky.DataAccess.Data;
using Bulky.DataAccess.Repository;
using Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

This is the error I get:

[image: The Error I encounter]

I tried to change the connections between data context and object which is created in relevant scope. I checked all dependencies and version implements.

Comment: Exceptions can be described as text, which is much easier for us to read and understand than images.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates `CategoryRepository` doesn't implement the interface

The CategoryRepository class you've shown  is under the `Bulky.DataAccess.Repository` namespace

```
namespace Bulky.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class CategoryRepository : Repository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(Category obj)
        {
            _db.Categories.Update(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

but in program.cs:

```
using Bulky.DataAccess.Repository
```

is in gray,which means your current  `CategoryRepository` is under another namespace

[image]

Try with full name when you regist the service:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, Bulky.DataAccess.Repository.CategoryRepository>();
```